# php session not working, tried all sorts

Tags: php, session, variables, global-variables

I've been stuck on a problem for the past 3 hours and its driving me mental in regards to PHP sessions. Iv moved on from session_is_registered to $_SESSION and it dont want to work.

See code below (is in all files right at very top on pages i ant to protect with login):

```
    <?php

     session_start();

     if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
         header("location: login.php");

    ?>
```

On another page access.php I have a form with two input boxes and submit button to check input and cross reference it with db. When incorrect values are entered i get message "Invalid login" which is right.. But when i type correct details leads me back to login.php page asking to login.

I am saving session and checking details as follows:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    include("dbfile.php");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE user=$username AND pass=$pass");

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1){

             $_SESSION['user'] = "Test";
             header("location: account.php");
    }else{

             header("location: login.php");      
    }
     ?>
```

unfortunately i am on a shared server which has register_globals off but am not sure if that is the problem. if i echo the output of the session o nother pages i get nothing. Like its not even registering/ssaving the session.

I have cookies/js enabled on browsers. Infact, i have tested on 4 browsers but same result. Whos gonna be the life saver on this one..

Comment: where is it ending up in that if statement is it going to login.php from there or is it going to account.php? maybe you have more than one row returned from db?

Comment: if one matching record is found it goes to my account page otherwise it goes to login.php. The username' in the db are set to unique hence, possibility of duplication is eliminated.

Comment: Can you post the PHP config part from phpinfo()? <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: can you var_dump($_SESSION) and die; and let me know what it displays?

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION) give u output or not???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `$_POST['username']` and `$POST['pass']` in your query, the variables `$username` and `$pass` don't exist if `register_globals` are turned off. (Which they should be.)

If you want to see whether sessions are working or not, try this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    var_dump($_SESSION);
    $_SESSION['works'] = 'yes';
?>
```

On the second page view you should get a result on the screen. :)

Comment: It does work ["works"]=> string(3) "yes" but why cant i access any other page.. i have session_start at top but sends ne back to login

Comment: That is because `register_globals` is turned off and your code relies on it being turned on. So as I posted, use `$_POST['username]` and `$_POST['pass']` to get the login values.

Comment: Also, take a look at the other answers recommending `mysql_real_escape_string`. It's a big improvement if you use this function!

Comment: its works mate! i stuck with $user, it was a silly mistake.. i had anotehr query with the same name in an included file (header) i changed the name and now everything workng like a charm.. your dumpvar was like a through ball lol.. Thanks a bunch!!

Answer (score 0):

try this one When u r usinvariable in query and the data type is integer then you have to write ".$variable_name." if variable is datatype is varchar then you have to write like "'.$varable_name.'"

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("dbfile.php");

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE user="'.$username.'" AND pass="'.$pass.'" ");

    if(mysql_num_rows($sql)==1){

             $_SESSION['user'] = "Test";
             header("location: account.php");
    }else{

             header("location: login.php");      
    }
     ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE user='$username' AND pass='$pass'");

if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){

         $_SESSION['user'] = "Test";
         header("location: account.php");
}else{
         // die(mysql_error()); use this if you think maybe there is an error
         header("location: login.php");      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting problem like your php session not working in all pages of your site, than don't worry here you can easily solve your problem if your problem match to my problem i have previously in my site and i solve.

So suppose in your login page you started your session as...

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['islogin'] = 'true';
```

but your 'islogin' session is not working for all the pages except few pages. Than may be there is problem in your url. Please check there is a 'www' in your url. If not than add 'www' in your url and try again. If you want to add 'www' in your url using htaccess file than try following.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Add these three lines of code in your .htaccess file.

May be this changes solve your problem.